# Observer pattern in NET Core

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, observer-pattern

I have a domain entity called *Transaction* and I want to receive notifications in my application services when some event occurs, like new transaction, updated transaction...

So, I readed this article from MSDN https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/events/observer-design-pattern, but I don't know if the observer pattern is the best aproach in NET Core.

Do I need to implement the IObservable in my domain entities?

Any suggestions?

Comment: As you said these are events. Therefore you should probably read about domain events.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to receive others' events, you should implement the IObservable interface.

IObserver should be provides by the publisher.

> I want to receive notifications in my application services when some event ocurss,

In your case, the "my application services".